# RTK Query useQuery hook: Error is not the value returned in transformErrorResponse

Tags: react-native, rtk-query

I have an endpoint with a query that has a `transformErrorResponse` applied to it where I return custom error objects.

```js
export const myAPI = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'myAPI',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://my.site.com/api/',
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUserInfo: builder.query<string, string>({
      query: (params) => ({
        url: 'user/' + params,
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: 1, // <-- intentionally short timeout to test this error case
      transformErrorResponse: async (baseQueryReturnValue) => {
        const err = {
           message: 'some custom error msg',
           code: 'custom code string here',
        };
        return err;
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetUserInfoQuery } = myAPI;
```

This works properly in all cases **EXCEPT** when the query is aborted due to a timeout ('TIMEOUT_ERROR').

In that case, I will always get the default error:

```json
{"message": "Aborted", "name": "AbortError"}
```

My `transformErrorResponse` code never gets used it seems.

I am getting the error by using the query via the useQuery hook like so:

```js
const { isLoading, isFetching, error, data } = useGetUserInfoQuery('userNameHere');
```

Is there some other place to customize the error that is returned on a rejected query due to a timeout?

Comment: Please [edit] to include a relevant [mcve] so we can see what your code is doing.

Comment: I've updated it now. Sorry about that

Comment: makes sense that it doesn't reach your code because the timeout is not an error response, it's an action of RTK-Query.  I don't see a way to handle timeouts in the docs though.

Comment: But if I log out to the console from inside the `transformErrorResponse` section, it logs out fine. But whatever I return there is not what gets put in the `"error"` prop of the hook.

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug. I see it in the Github Issue tracker for RTK (issue #2915) and is slated for fixing in the 1.9.x Milestone.

I will implement a janky workaround for now. But good to know I'm not going insane